# Docker Add File After Image Creation and Before Container Initiation

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-fargate

Is it possible to intervene docker lifecycle manually using AWS Fargate ?

Current Situation : 
docker create (it will create container in halted state)
adding some additional files in container (which i can't add in image)
and then docker start to startcontainer

Can I do achieve this file if I am using AWS fargate using task definition ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is mounting a volume in a `docker` container to access the file system. Unfortunately Fargate only supports non-persistent storage. So you cannot specify the volume of your choice where your files exist.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/fargate-task-storage.html

The only storage that `Fargate` support is a request for an empty space for ephimeral usage by your container.

On a brighter side, a request is open to support `EFS` with `Fargate`. https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/53

Comment: Thanks for the response but the question is not about mounting a storage. Its something like this :     Internally fargate simply dones docker run but what I want is to add a certificate after creating container and before starting it (because its a private cert) . For that , I want control on docker create and docker start command . Is it possible in fargate ?

Comment: No that is not possible.

Comment: I am assuming you meant entrypoint. The original post was asking fargate task definition to copy over a file to a container. The “entrypoint” is a docker’s concept. Not something introduced in Fargate.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question is **ENTRYPOINT**

When we create our dockerfile which is to be executed in fargate task definition , we have to create an entrypoint in the dockerfile or in task definition of fargate which will be executed first as soon as container is running . That's where we can write execute shell script which should be pre-copied in the docker image while building .  Shell script should contain your import statements of sensitive files.

This way they will not be part of image but still will be part of your container.